# Can someone explain to me what the sentence means?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english, australian-english

> I was anxious to get him here, away from family and friends.

Here who is away from family and friends? Is that he or I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I was anxious to get him here, away from family and friends.

The second part of the sentence after the comma refers to **him**. We can separate it like this:

- I was anxious to get him here.
- I was anxious to get him away from family and friends.